# Git Add command gets fatal: pathspec on existing file

Tags: git

I have installed Git on Windows 10, created a new folder and executed a git init successfully and created a file named "test1.html" in the same folder. The "git add test1.html" command from the git bash console returns the following error message:

fatal: pathspec 'test1.html' did not match any files

executing an "ls -la" command returns proof the hidden .git subfolder is there along with the file I'm trying to add. Screenshot included shows such.

Any ideas what's wrong?

[image]

Comment: `ls -la | cat -ETv` See https://linux.die.net/man/1/cat

Comment: @phd Good trick. I have referenced your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 3):

Confirm first that `ls 'test1.html'` does work, in case the filename ends with (invisible) spaces.

Then try the same `git add` in a CMD (without git bash) to see if the issue persists.

As [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67954920/git-add-command-gets-fatal-pathspec-on-existing-file/67955081#comment120116137_67954920), using [`cat -ETv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cat), with -v for "`--show-nonprinting`", you can see if there are any extra space by looking at the trailing '`$`' in:

```sh
vonc@vclp MINGW64 ~/git/gitw (bubbletea)
$ ls -la | cat -ETv
total 13785$
drwxr-xr-x 1 vonc 197121       0 Jun 12 21:18 .$
drwxr-xr-x 1 vonc 197121       0 Jun  9 00:12 ..$
drwxr-xr-x 1 vonc 197121       0 Jun 13 11:49 .git$
-rw-r--r-- 1 vonc 197121      21 May 29 22:59 .gitattributes$
-rw-r--r-- 1 vonc 197121      88 Jun 10 20:44 .gitignore$
-rw-r--r-- 1 vonc 197121     511 Jun 11 18:41 go.mod$
-rw-r--r-- 1 vonc 197121    7418 Jun 11 18:41 go.sum$
drwxr-xr-x 1 vonc 197121       0 May 30 00:03 internal$
-rw-r--r-- 1 vonc 197121   12428 Jun 10 20:44 main.go$
```

Answer (score 1):

try to run this commmand.
`git config core.longpaths true`